# Error "Host x.x.x.x is not allowed to connect to this mariaDB server"

Tags: mysql, c#, xampp, mariadb

Tengo un codigo de c# que funciona con una base de datos para guardar y gestionar datos de una libreria, pero a la hora de conectarla me da este error

He estado siguiendo las siguientes instrucciones para intentar solucionarlo pero ninguno parece solucionar el problema
https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/sqlstatehy000-1130-host-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server?expand_article=1
https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/03/26/mysql-solucion-host-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mariadb-server/

Antes estaba trabajando con el siguiente codigo para declarar la conexion con la base de datos lo cual tambien me tiraba una excepcion por culpa de un `.toString()` que al parecer esta obsoleto, lo solucione y el codigo quedo asi

```
public AccesoBD()
{
    try
    {
        servidor = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["192.168.60.54"];
        bdNombre = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["libreriawindowsform"];
        usuario = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["antonio"];
        contrasena = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""];
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

protected void abrirConexion()
{
    try
    {
        conexion = new MySqlConnection();
        conexion.ConnectionString = "Server=" + servidor + "; Database=" + bdNombre + "; Uid=" + usuario + "; Pwd=" + contrasena + ";SslMode=none;";
        conexion.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

Me gustaria saber como puedo hacer para que la conexion se haga adecuadamente he intentado conectarme por terminal con mi ip privada y mi usuario (que no tiene contraseña) y la conexion se ha hecho correctamente por lo que el problema seguramente venga de parte de c#.

Tambien los nuget parecen ser correctos adjunto captura de cuales tengo instalados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado con esta conecction string? "Server=" + servidor + "; Database=" + bdNombre + "; user=" + usuario + "; password=" + contrasena + ";SslMode=none;"

Comment: quizas serviría tener un poco mas de info, el "código en c#" se ejecuta en el mismo host que cuando te conectás por consola?

Comment: El problema fue que no estaba declarando bien el appSeting me lo comentaron en la pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77156169/error-host-x-x-x-x-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mariadb-server?noredirect=1#comment136019738_77156169 y me pasaron la documentacion